# Add references to Visual c++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, wxwidgets

I tried to add references to wxwidgets. From their website I've got 16 .dll files as a realese of the project.

I paste it everywhere in solution folder and "Add Reference" in project properties have empty list anyway. I read tons of tutorials, watched like all totorial movies I found, but I just cant add it to my project. Im new in C++, as long as I was programming in C# all i need to do there was: click on reference->add and thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may come as a surprise, but C++ is different from C#. You don't use references in it at all. See the [last section of docs/msw/install.txt](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/msw/install.txt#L485) for what you need to do to build C++ projects using wxWidgets.

Comment: Really????? That claim is definitely not true: "It may come as a surprise, but C++ is different from C#. You don't use references in it at all."!

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what kind of references this comment was about. But I'm not really sure what do you disagree with, to be honest.

Comment: Apparently in C++/CX project you can have References. Also in the Android mobile development as supported by VS2015 extension you can have References. So just claiming: "You don't use references in it at all." isn't accurate at all.

Comment: C++/CX is not really C++ at all. And surely you can't be nitpicking about not taking into account Android support in MSVS back in 2014, before it was added to it (let alone to the 2012 version)? Seriously, what's your point?

Comment: No offense, sorry! The Microsoft SDKs I am using are either Referenced or installed as NuGet packages. IMO Microsoft doesn't view References as something language specific. So this can be confusing to a beginner.